# When Front page and Posts page are specified is it possible to just have front-page.php as the home page?

Tags: frontpage

Right now I have a Front page and a Posts page specified in dashboard. The Front page is a page called "home" using a page-home.php template.

However I don't want to have to create a WP page for the home page, I just want WP to use my front-page.php or home.php template. And at the same time I still want it to have a specific page for posts.

How to do that, is it even possible?

Comment: What you're asking, or perhaps how you're asking it is a bit confusing. Perhaps you can clarify by mapping out what you hope to view where, e.g.

    / => Front page => page-home.php;
    /blog => Posts page => home.php;
    /posts => static page => page-posts.php

Answer (score 0):

For WordPress to automatically use home.php to render your home page you have to set

Settings > Reading > Home Page Displays to "Your latest posts"

With that option set WordPress looks to use home.php first, and then index.php (in that order) to output your home page.

Read more [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page).